# Как убрать redirect в функции и остаться на нынешней странице Django

Tags: python, django

Такой вопрос, есть функция добавления товара в корзину и она используется на разных страницах сайта, но редирект идёт только на главную страницу, нужно чтобы функция оставляла нас на той же странице на которой мы находимся. Как поменять функцию так, чтобы была возможность остаться на нынешней странице?

views.py

```
@require_POST
def cart_add(request, post_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    post = get_object_or_404(Posts, id=post_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(post=post)
    return redirect('home')
```

urls.py

```
path('cart/<int:post_id>/', cart_add, name='cart_add'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно просто "в лоб" сделать редирект на ту же страницу используя атрибут `HTTP_REFERER`:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

[Оригинал вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39560175/redirect-to-same-page-after-post-method-using-class-based-views)